# Making text bold using Stream Writer in C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How to make text bold using stream writer,here is my code:

```
 string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\WZ.PNR";
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
 textPrint.ToText(writer, Width, FSection, FAlign, DSection, DAlign, Format);
 writer.WriteLine();                   
 writer.Close();
```

I am writing some text and i need to make some text BOLD, How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: That really depends on what kind of file you are outputting. If it is a word file, then you will have to look at the word docs to see how to do this. you can't do this in a simple text file since there is no such concept as bold/italics etc in a simple text file. It's simple text.

Comment: Its actually a wordpad file(.PNR)

Comment: You've now claimed it's a WordPad file *and* a printer file. Which is it? When I try to save a file in WordPad, the options are RTF, Text Document, Text Document (MS-DOS format) or Unicode Text Document. Nothing mentioning PNR at all.

Answer (score 7):

`StreamWriter` is for writing plain text. You need markup of some kind to make text bold. Options include:

- RTF
- HTML
- TeX

How are you expecting to open the generated file? The application will need to understand whatever file format you choose. There's no general concept of "a bold character" - the letter E is the letter E; if you want it styled that styling data is separate.

Given your file extension, are you trying to create a [PeerNet Label Designer](http://filext.com/file-extension/PNR) file? If so, you'll need to find out the appropriate file format - I don't know whether it's a text format, binary etc.

Answer (score 2):

At first you should create your path in that way:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "WZ.PNR");
```

After this little improvement let's take a look at your pnr file...

So you open this file and like to write some bold text to it?

So do you have some kind of program, that is already able to create and view such a .pnr file?

I think you'll have, or from where do you know, that it is possible to have bold text within such a file?

In case you have this program to generate such a file with bold text. Just make a new file, enter three words: "one two three" and make the 'two' bold. Save this file and open it with a good plain text editor (e.g. notepad++) or a good Hex-Editor and try to find out how this will be accomplished.

For example, open WordPad create a new rtf-File and insert the above example. After saving it and re-opening in a plain text editor you'll get:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 one \b two\b0  three\par
}
```

And as you can see, the bold is been made by using '\b ' to enable and '\b0 ' to disable the bold text. Also there is plenty of other informations like used font, charset, etc.

That's called reverse-engineering if you don't have any specs. ;-)

Comment: What my application does is...Writes some text to .PNR file and user can view same content in windows Form and user prints the file.Once user closes the form .PNR file will be deleted..

Comment: Which application opens the .PNR file though?

Answer (score 1):

The extension PNR suggests some sort of Printer file. That means you'll have to look up the escape codes for that particular kind of printer.